# WPF MVVM Toggle button enabled/disabled during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mvvm, icommand

I would like to set a button to disabled and activate it at runtime when another method sets the _canExecute field to true.
Unfortunately I don't know how to trigger this event and update the view.
The CommandHandler class already implements RaiseCanExecuteChanged. But it's unclear how to use it.

**View**

```
<Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" />
```

**ViewModel**

```
public ViewModel(){

    _canExecute = false;
}


private bool _canExecute;

private ICommand _clickCommand;
public ICommand ClickCommand => _clickCommand ?? (_clickCommand = new CommandHandler(MyAction, _canExecute));



private void MyAction()
{
    // Do something after pressing the button
}


private void SomeOtherAction(){

    // If all expectations are satisfied, the button should be enabled.
    // But how does it trigger the View to update!?

    _canExecute = true;

}
```

**CommandHandler**

```
public class CommandHandler : ICommand
    {
        private Action _action;
        private bool _canExecute;
        public CommandHandler(Action action, bool canExecute)
        {
            _action = action;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _action();
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }


    }
```

Comment: Just update the command's `_canExecute` field and call its `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method.

Comment: If you implement INotifyPropertyChanged, you can instead bind IsEnabledProperty of your button to a property in your ViewModel

Comment: @DanieleSartori For what reason? ICommand already supports disabling controls. No need for another mechanism.

Comment: @Clemens: Not sure where/how to trigger RaiseCanExecuteChanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a method like this to your CommandHandler class:

```
public void SetCanExecute(bool canExecute)
{
    _canExecute = canExecute;
    RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

Then change the type of the ClickCommand property to CommandHandler

```
public CommandHandler ClickCommand => ...
```

and just call

```
ClickCommand.SetCanExecute(true);
```

Comment: Perfect! Expectations are fulfilled. Thank you!